# I want to convert base64 to json

Tags: python, json, binary, base64

I want to convert from base64 to json. Existing files are .jpg, and the purpose is to load multiple files in one folder and make them into one json.

```
import base64
import json
import os

directory = os.listdir('C:/users/user/desktop/k-means/image')
os.chdir('C:/users/user/desktop/k-means/image')
data={}

for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'rb')
    image_read = open_file.read()
    image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
    data[""] = image_64_encode.decode('ascii')
    with open('words.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as make_file:
        print(json.dumps(data))
```

The desired output is as follows. How do I modify my code?

```
{"data": 
"AAAAAGHLd/f39/clOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==", "label": 5}
{"data": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==", "label": 0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import base64
import json
import os
from pprint import pprint

directory = os.listdir('C:/users/user/desktop/k-means/image')
os.chdir('C:/users/user/desktop/k-means/image')
data={}

for file in directory:
    base = os.path.basename(file)
    data["label"] = base
    open_file = open(file,'rb')
    image_read = open_file.read()
    image_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(image_read)
    data["data"] = image_64_encode.decode('ascii') 
    final_data = json.dumps(data)
    final_data = json.loads(final_data)
    pprint(final_data)

#output: {"data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFB...", "label": "Capture.JPG"}
```

**Note**: `encodestring` is a deprecated alias since Python3.1, I've used `encodebytes` instead.

To write this `final_data` to a json file, you must enclose the loop inside the `open` function for *words.json*:

```
with open('words.json', 'w') as make_file:
    for file in directory:
        base = os.path.basename(file)
        data["label"] = base
        open_file = open(file,'rb')
        image_read = open_file.read()
        image_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(image_read)
        data["data"] = image_64_encode.decode('ascii') 
        final_data = json.dumps(data)
        make_file.write(final_data)
```